# How do I drop down the Google Chrome menus with the keyboard?

Tags: google-chrome

The Google Chrome Page and Tools menus have no visible mnemonic that indicates how to drop them down with the keyboard. Is there a way?

Comment: adding "windows" tag as I'm not sure how much of this applies to Linux and Mac

Comment: Removed »windows« tag again as it works on Linux too, at least.

Answer (score 10):

Alt-E drops down the Page menu 
Alt-F drops down the Tools menu (wrench)

Comment: Note this tested on Chrome 4.0 for Windows.

Comment: This answer made my hair grow back and made me more virile!

Comment: Tested and works on Chrome 4.0.249.43 for Ubuntu 9.10.

Answer (score 5):

to navigate *all* the Google Chrome menus, per

http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96831

> **Shift+Alt+T**: Set keyboard focus on the Google Chrome toolbar. Use your right and left arrow keys to navigate to different buttons on the toolbar.

Comment: True, but that's like me asking out to drop down the Tools menu in Explorer and answering "F10". It's taking the long way.

Comment: Additional tip for this: if you press the down arrow to expand either of the drop down menus, hit ESC to be back at the parent level where you can then continue using left and arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work on Mac.

Tried Cmd E/F, Alt E/F, and Ctrl E/F

None do anything.  Then again, Mac Chrome currently doesn't even have a damn bookmark manager.

Answer (score 0):

[Chrome Keyboard & Mouse Shortcuts](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95743)

- Alt+E = Open Page Menu
- Alt+F = Open Tools Menu